# Boostrap styles not getting overriden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I have imported my custom CSS file below the bootstrap CDN but still it is not getting overridden.
[here is the screenshot of inspecting element.][1]

> Importing bootstrap and css

```
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <!--Custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/base.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/cart.css' %}" />
```

> My custom style (to override bootstrap)

```
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code, not images of it

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected:

`*` is of lower priority than `p` (or any selector), so the boostrap code will be more important.

The order of the files only matters when two selectors with the same priority exist. In that case the file loaded latest will win.

To fix this, do:

```
p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

And you'll see your code applying.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. Got to override a lot when using bootstrap phew!

Comment: Cheers :). Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.